# Go: XORKeyStream(): runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go, null

When I try to run the following code (I'm trying to encrypt the byte array representation of a string, using AES in CFB mode) I get an *invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference* error, on the line *sEnc.XORKeyStream(msgB, msgB)*. The documentation says the source and destination for XORKeyStream can be the same byte array (also tried using a separate destination, but no dice), but I can't figure out what's causing the error. I'm using the latest version of the Go App Engine SDK on OS X Lion.

Since at this point I'm still trying to get the code to simply *encrypt something*, I'm just generating a random key and not bothering to store it yet.

```
func generateKey(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    key := make([]byte, 32)
    n, err := rand.Read(key)
    err = err
    if(err != nil) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, err)
        return
    }
    if(n != 32) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Not enough bytes read.")
        return
    }
    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if(err != nil) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, err)
    }

    iv := make([]byte, 32)
    n, err = rand.Read(iv)
    err = err
    if(err != nil) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, err)
        return
    }
    if(n != 32) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Not enough bytes read.")
        return
    }

    sEnc := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(c, iv)

    msg := "text to be encrypted"
    msgR := strings.NewReader(msg)
    msgB := make([]byte, msgR.Len())
    n, err = msgR.Read(msgB)
    if(err != nil) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, err)
        return
    }
    if(n == 0) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "No bytes read.")
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, msgB)
    fmt.Fprint(w, "<br>")
    sEnc.XORKeyStream(msgB, msgB)
    fmt.Fprint(w, msgB)
}
```

The error messages:

> 2011/08/15 15:15:58 http: panic serving : runtime error: invalid
>   memory address or nil pointer dereference   runtime.panic
>   /private/tmp/appengine/google_appengine/goroot/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1041
>   runtime.panicstring
>   /private/tmp/appengine/google_appengine/goroot/src/pkg/runtime/runtime.c:116
>   runtime.sigpanic
>   /private/tmp/appengine/google_appengine/goroot/src/pkg/runtime/darwin/thread.c:470
>   server.generateKey server/server.go:66   http.HandlerFunc·ServeHTTP
>   /private/tmp/appengine/google_appengine/goroot/src/pkg/http/server.go:589
>   http.*ServeMux·ServeHTTP
>   /private/tmp/appengine/google_appengine/goroot/src/pkg/http/server.go:790
>   appengine_internal.handleFilteredHTTP
>   /private/tmp/appengine/google_appengine/goroot/src/pkg/appengine_sdk/go_appengine_sdk/appengine_internal/api_dev.go:58
>   http.HandlerFunc·ServeHTTP
>   /private/tmp/appengine/google_appengine/goroot/src/pkg/http/server.go:589
>   http.*conn·serve
>   /private/tmp/appengine/google_appengine/goroot/src/pkg/http/server.go:555
>   runtime.goexit
>   /private/tmp/appengine/google_appengine/goroot/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:178
>   INFO     2011-08-15 15:15:58,310 dev_appserver.py:4248] "GET
>   /genkey/aes256 HTTP/1.1" 500 -

I've posted [the rest of the code](http://pastebin.com/2Aqzt8VA) to paste bin, but it's just the includes/init function, nothing all that interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sEnc` is `nil` as a result of an error. For [`cipher.NewCFBEncrypter`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#Stream.NewCFBEncrypter), "the iv must be the same length as the Block's block." The AES block size is 128 bits or 16 bytes? For example,

```
iv := make([]byte, c.BlockSize())
```

Comment: Ah, I see! I mistakenly assumed that the block size was the same size as the key! That fixed the issue.